# Can someone tell me the meaning of the picture table section?

Tags: typescript

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gC86.png)

Table is:

| Declaration Type | Namespace | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Namespace | X |  | X |
| Class |  | X | X |
| Enum |  | X | X |
| Interface |  | X |  |
| Type Alias |  | X |  |
| Function |  |  | X |
| Variable |  |  | X |

According to the [doc context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts), I could understand what this table shows me is that: `Namespace` can only generate Namespace type, `Type` can generate Class, Enum, Interface and Type Alias, `Value` can create Namespace, Class, Enum, Function and Variable. But why use the "x" symbol? My first impression is that "x" represents the inability to create.

My question is:

1. Is my understanding above correct?
2. Does the document use the symbol 'x' to indicate ambiguity?

Comment: I think you have the relationship reversed: that table lists different kinds of declaration statements in the first column, and describes which kinds of identifiers (entities) are created in the type system as a result in the remaining columns. e.g. an _interface_ identifier can’t be used in a position where a value is required, and a _function_ identifier can’t be used in a position where a type is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret the information in the table this way:

There are four columns, each with a heading and rows of cells below. The leftmost column heading contains "Declaration Type", and the cells below contain descriptions of the different kinds of declaration *entities* that TypeScript understands:

- Namespace
- Class
- Enum
- Interface
- Type Alias
- Function
- Variable

The other columns represent categories in the type system:

- Namespace
- Type
- Value

The presence of an `x` symbol in one of the category columns indicates that the corresponding entity to the left of the `x` can be used in the program in that category.

As an example — an *interface* can be used in a program where a *type* is expected, but cannot be used where a *value* or *namespace* is expected:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHt1QCajpAZ2QG8AoZZADwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuc5AT1oZfdIBfUqQToQBMMgAO6UGACMtDFlwh8EIgF4SVWgCYANN1oBmZII6jxkmXPD7kOlTjyEOQA)

```ts
interface Coordinates {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

const point1: Coordinates = { x: 2, y: 3 };
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^ Ok!

const point2 = Coordinates; /*
               ~~~~~~~~~~~ Error
'Coordinates' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693) */
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient response; your answer saved my mind. This means: `Class` Declaration can be both Type and Value, This is why we can use a Class to type a variable in typescript.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77175302/can-someone-tell-me-the-meaning-of-the-picture-table-section/77175794?noredirect=1#comment136054965_77175794) @wangxdmm Exactly.